# Graphviz: Place edge label on the other side (II)

Tags: graphviz

related questions are:

[Graphviz: Place edge label on the other side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450700/graphviz-place-edge-label-on-the-other-side)

[How to place edge labels ON edge in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350617/how-to-place-edge-labels-on-edge-in-graphviz)

Consider following dot file:

```
digraph {
0 -> 1 [ len=2, label="(1, 0)"];
0 -> 1 [ len=0.5, dir=none, weight=10];
1 -> 0 [ len=2, label="(0, -1)"];
}
```

giving following result:

[image]

How can I manage to get a symmetric version? `(0,-1)` should be left of the right egde.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As you've found out, graphviz doesn't let you choose horizontal label placement, so all solutions are slightly hacky.

**Attempt #1: The two solutions posted by marapet ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450700/graphviz-place-edge-label-on-the-other-side))**

1. The labelangle and labeldistance trick doesn't adapt well to
   different lengths of label text (you'd have to recalculate new
   distance/angle numbers).
2. The splines=false trick doesn't work so well where the number of
       edges between nodes > the number of nodes (you end up with
       overlapping edges).

**Attempt #2: xlabels and anchors to create curved edges**

This uses a relatively new feature of graphviz, [xlabel](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:xlabel) (which places the label AFTER the coordinates for the nodes/edges have been decided). The [ports](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#kportPos) feature is used to create curved edges. The padding on the labels is achieved with space characters.

[image: gv]

```
digraph {
forcelabels=true;

    0:sw -> 1:nw [ dir=forward, xlabel="  (1, 0)  "];
    0 -> 1 [dir=none];
    1:ne -> 0:se [ dir=backward, xlabel= "  (0, -1)  "];

}
```

I believe you need graphviz version >2.29 to use xlabel.

Comment: In my version of dot (2.40) it no longer seems to be possible to use spaces to control the label position.

Comment: @Nathaniel, in case it helps try to prepend/append some nearly unseen character, like the dot (`.`) or something else in the Unicode table. This might then register as a character the layout engine will use including your spaces: `xlabel=".                    mytext"` or `xlabel="mytext                  ."`.